Ratio of spherical metric on the boundary at infinity of hyperbolic n-space
I was trying to learn construction of Patterson-Sullivan measures following Sullivan's paper. However, I had some confusions on showing the construction is a conformal density. We denote by $H$ the hyperbolic $(d+1)$-space with boundary at infinity $S^d$. For any $x\in H$, we denote by $\mu_x$ the Patterson-Sullivan measure. From the construction, we know that the ratio $\frac{d\mu_{y}}{d\mu_x}(\xi)=e^{-\delta(x,y)_{\xi}}$ where $\xi\in S^d$, $\delta$ is the critical exponent, and $(x,y)_{\xi}$ denotes the signed distance between the horospheres. To show the Patterson-Sullivan measures are conformal density, we need the metric on $S^d$. For any point $p\in H$, he used the spherical metric associated to $p$ by radial projection. Here is my first question:

What is the spherical metric associated to $p$? Is it the angular metric i.e. $d_p(\xi,\eta)$ equals the angle between two geodesics $[p,\xi]$ and $[p,\eta]$? But I think it should be Riemannian metric on $S^d$. It seems there is a canonical way reconstruct Riemannian metric from a metric answered here. However, it's still not clear for me what this Riemannian or spherical metric is.

Then we are left to show the ratio $\frac{d_{y}}{d_{x}}(\xi)=e^{(x,y)_{\xi}}$. The paper argued that consider the upper half plane model with $\xi$ as origin. The parabolic element $\gamma_1$ which sends $x,y$ to points $\rho_x,\rho_y$ on the verticle line has derivative $1$ at $\xi$ and a homothety $\gamma_2$ sending $\rho_x$ to $\rho_y$ with derivative $e^{d(\rho_x,\rho_y)}$. I am confused that:

Why the derivative of parabolic element has derivative $1$ at $\xi=0$?

How does the derivative of $\gamma_2,\gamma_1$ relate to the ratio $\frac{d_y}{d_x}(\xi)$?


Thanks for your help in advance and I'd also appreciate any references!

There are many places where this is better explained than in Sullivan's paper. Consider reading for instance the book by Nicholls.

@MoisheKohan thanks for your suggestion! I am confused that Nicholls defined the derivative as $$|\gamma_x'(\xi)|:=\lim_{\eta\to\xi}\frac{d_x(\gamma(\xi),\gamma(\eta))}{d_x(\xi,\eta)}$$ where $B$ the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $x\in B, \xi\in\partial B$, $\gamma$ is Moebius preserving $B$, $d_x$ the angular metric based at $x$. By computation, we derived this "derivative" $|\gamma_x'(\xi)|$ equals $e^{(x,\gamma^{-1}x)_{\xi}}$ which coincides with the value of linear derivative described above. But a priori, how do we know they are the same (like in Sullivan's argument)?

I do not think we are born with this kind of knowledge. The same applies to most mathematical results.

Your post has a lot of questions, and I'll answer just the first one. (For the others I suggest separate posts, following our suggestions here regarding "one question per post").
But as an aside before starting, although one can always derive a metric space metric from a Riemannian metric (by minimizing path length, assuming connectivity), one cannot always go in the other direction. Many metric space metrics have nothing to do with a Riemannian metric. For one, the underlying space might not even be a manifold; and even if it is, manifolds can have many weird metric space metrics. So if you have a manifold (e.g. the sphere at infinity) and if you want to define a metric on that manifold that is derived from a Riemannian metric, then you had better work directly with the Riemannian metric; you can always reconstruct the metric space metric from that.
To get to your question, here's a quick summary, with details to follow: the spherical metric on $S^d$ associated to a point $p \in \mathbb H^{d+1}$ is indeed the angular metric $d_p(\xi,\eta)$ at $p$ between the rays $[p,\xi]$ and $[p,\eta]$, and it is indeed derived from a Riemannian metric on $S^d$ that I'll denote $g_p$; but, as $p$ varies over $H^{d+1}$ these metrics on $S^d$ are not all the same. Here's some details.
For each $p \in H^{d+1}$ the Riemannian metric on $H^{d+1}$ gives us an inner product on the tangent space $T_p H^{d+1}$, which induces an isometry $T_p H^{p+1} \approx \mathbb R^{d+1}$, which induces a Riemannian metric on any smooth submanifold of $T_p$, and so in particular a Riemannian metric on the unit tangent sphere $T^1_p \subset T_p$. The metric space metric derived from that Riemannian metric on $T^1_p$ is, by definition, the angular metric on $T^1_p$.
Now let's project that metric out to the sphere at infinity $S^d$. Each unit vector $u \in T^1_p$ is tangent to a well-defined ray $R_u = [p,\xi_u] \in \overline H^{d+1} = H^{d+1} \cup S^d$ ending at a well-defined point at infinity $\xi_u \in S^d$. This function $u \mapsto \xi_u$ is, by definition, the projection function $T^1_p \mapsto S^d$. This projection function is smooth, and therefore the Riemannian metric on $T^1_p$ pushes forward to a Riemannian metric on $S^d$ that I will denote $g_p$.
This construction has an important property (easily derived): for any isometry $\phi \in \text{Isom}(H^{d+1})$ and any point $q \in H^{d+1}$ with image point $p = \phi(q) \in H^{d+1}$, the isometry $\phi$ induces a conformal map $\phi : S^d \to S^d$, and it is not hard to prove that $\phi_* g_q = g_p$.
To complete the derivation, if we use the Poincaré ball model $H^{d+1} \subset \mathbb R^{d+1}$ and $q = \mathcal O$ (the origin), then it should be obvious that $g_q$ is the Riemannian metric on $S^d \subset \mathbb R^{d+1}$ induced from the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^{d+1}$. And therefore the metric space metric on $S^d$ that is induced by $g_{\mathcal O}$ is indeed the ordinary Euclidean angular metric on $S^{d+1}$. But now, when you choose some other point $p \in H^{d+1}$ and you push forward under an isometry $\phi$ taking $\mathcal O$ to $p$, you can see that you get the angular metric induced from $g_p$. And of $p \ne \mathcal O$ then this is not the same as the ordinary Euclidean angular metric $g_{\mathcal O}$!!

Thanks for your detailed answer! It makes sense for me what the spherical metrics are. For example, we call $d_0$ the angular metric induced from $g_{\mathcal{O}}$. Then $d_p(\eta, \xi)=d_0(T(\eta), T(\xi))$ where $T$ sends $p$ to $\mathcal{O}$ preserving the ball. However, I am still trying to figure out the ratio $g_p/g_q(\xi)=\frac{\phi_*(g_q)}{g_q}(\xi)$ i.e. how $\phi$ distorted the inner product at $\xi$ and show it equals $e^{(q,p)_{\xi}}$. Would you mind giving me a hint? @Lee Mosher

So our general guidelines, as indicated in my link, is one question per post. If you have another question, make another post!
